# typing.NamedTuple and PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.5

How can I make typing.NamedTuple play nicely with PyCharm?

collections.namedtuple works fine:

```
import collections
B = collections.namedtuple('B', ['i'])
b = B(1)
b.i
```

but typing.NamedTuple doesn't:

```
import typing
A = typing.NamedTuple('A', [('i', int)])
a = A(1)
a. # No suggestions
```

Comment: There are loads of open tickes regarding this issue. You can help by voting and commenting. I collected those issues: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18246#comment=27-2093804

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should better direct such questions to the [PyCharm bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project%3A%20PyCharm).
Your problem already has an open [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18246) though.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm plays very well with the prefered syntax

```
class A(NamedTuple):
    i: int
```

Comment: Only Python >=3.6 support this. The question was about python 3.5 and not actual anymore. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: It only plays well when the class is declared at module level.